# I want to save an unordered list to a column in a database on android phonegap

Tags: php, android, html, ajax, cordova

I want to save an unordered list to a column in a database. How can i do this ?

- CHESSE
- HAM

CREATE TABLE INGREDIENTE ( name varchar(20), ingredients varchar(30);

I want to put the list in the ingredients part.

Here is my code in the html and js i use to create the list.

```
function selectIngredient(select)
    { 
      var $ul = $(select).closest('.ui-select').prev('ul');
console.log($ul[0])
  if ($ul.find('input[value=' + $(select).val() + ']').length == 0) {
    console.log('s')
        $ul.append('<li onclick="$(this).remove();">' +
          '<input type="hidden" name="ingredients[]" value="' + 
          $(select).val() + '" /> ' +
          $(select).find('option:selected').text() + '</li>');
  }
    }




<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
    <title>Ingredient</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/receta.min.css" />
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/receta.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
      <script src="recetas.js">  </script>  

</head>
     <body>
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
Receta: <input type="text" name="receta">
Ingredientes: <input type="text" name="ingredientes">

      <input type="submit">      

             <label>Ingredientes</label>
    <ul>

    </ul>

    <select onchange="selectIngredient(this);">
     <option value="Cheese">Cheese</option>
     <option value="Olives">Olives</option>
     <option value="Pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
     <option value="Milk">Milk</option>
    </select> 

         </body>
      </html>



<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'alanis_lozano';
$dbpass = '20Anahuac12';

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die                      ('Error connecting to mysql');

$dbname = 'alanis_recetas';
mysql_select_db($dbname, $conn);

$sql="INSERT INTO Recetas (receta, ingredientes)
VALUES
('$_POST[receta]',$ingredientes = join(',', $_POST['selections'])";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$conn))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

[image]

Comment: I am using eclipse, phonegap, html and php. I already made the database test of adding the name and it works fine. But i dont know how to add a list. Heres how i added the name Name: <input type="text" name="name">

Comment: What triggers the save?  Is there a button?  A form?  You realize a list is output, not input, right?  Sounds more like you would want the list to come from the DB... you should probably have a form to input to the DB

Comment: No the list is in the html and then you send it to the database. But i have a question the list doesnt have the same values everytime. It changes its a list with like 100 differente things. And the user selects only the ones that he is going to use.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365997/jquery-get-select-options-to-array

Comment: I see what you're doing now... you really ought to implement something with AJAX for this, but you'll also have to reconsider the design of your database.  You should have a separate table for `ingredients`, with a foreign key to the `recipes` table, so that you can store one ingredient per row.

Comment: But if i want to put all in one row ?

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the list into a comma delimited string:

```
$ingredients = join(',', $_POST['selections']);
```

In the dom you can name the select box selections.

Comment: But i have a question the list doesnt have the same values everytime. It changes its a list with like 100 differente things. And the user selects only the ones that he is going to use.

Comment: I just posted all the code including php. I know theres something wrong but i cant find it.

Comment: FYI - join() is DEPRECATED in PHP.  Use implode() instead.

Answer (score 0):

What you really want to do here is store ingredients in a delimited fashion, and format them into a list on output.

Try something like this:

```
<form action="save.php">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <textarea name="ingredients"></textarea>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

**save.php** - Replace any delimiter character with a newline (\n) character before saving

```
<?php

$name = $_GET["name"];
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($name);

$ingredients = $_GET["ingredients"];
$ingredients = mysqli_real_escape_string($ingredients);
$ingredients = preg_replace("/[,\.\n\t]+/", "\n", $ingredients);
```

**display.php** - Before displaying, split up your ingredients by the newline character and render them in a UL

```
echo "<ul>";
$ingredients = explode('\n", $ingredients);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($ingredients); $i++) {
    echo "<li>{$ingredients[$i]}</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```